# How do i pass an id as a parameter for a function using the click eventListener in jquery?

Tags: jquery, parameters

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //for example item is the button that will be clicked and panelContent is the panel that will be shown
    $('#item').click({param1: '#panelContent'}, toggleObjects);

    // i tried this also and it doesn't work
    $('#item').click(toggleObjects('#panelContent'));
});
var currentObject;
function toggleObjects(theObject) {
    //theObject is the id of the panel 
    if(currentObject===null)
    {
        currentObject=theObject;
        $(currentObject).show();
    }
    if(currentObject===theObject)
    {
        $(theObject).toggle();
    }
    if(currentObject!==theObject)
    {
        $(currentObject).hide();
        currentObject=theObject;
        $(currentObject).show();
    }
    console.log( 'executed!' );
}
</script>
```

If i put onclick="toggleObjects('#panelContent')" on the button in html it works fine, but i would like to use the jquery event listener.

How should i use the .click event for passing the function and also the parameter?
 Or is there another solution besides the html onclick version ?

Please excuse my poor English!
Thank you in advance for your attention to this matter.

Comment: is your currentObject is beginning with `#` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What it appears you want is either an in-line function--

```
$('#item').click(function() { toggleObjects('#panelContent'); } );
```

Or to define a new function that calls the toggleObjects function with the specific parameter --

```
var toggleObjectsWithPanelContent = function() {
  toggleObjects('#panelContent');
};
$('#item').click(toggleObjectsWithPanelContent);
```

.

You got close with `$('#item').click(toggleObjects('#panelContent'));`,

but the `toggleObjects('#panelContent')` bit is actually a function call there, not a reference to a function, so you're actually passing the return value of toggleObjects to the click() fn. (The return value in this case being `undefined`).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand now.:D. I thought by click(toggleObjects('#panelContent') it would use the toggleObjects function instead of the function(){} that is declared.

Answer (score 0):

You are right but If you write like this

```
<input type="button " id="item" onclick="toggleObjects('panelContent');" />
```

pass the `id` not the **id with #**.

then it will hit the function `toggleObjects` in your script accepting the parameter you are passing . 
If you want this using **jQuery click event handler** , then do this :-

```
 $("#item").click(function(){
     toggleObjects('panelContent'); 
 });
```

And if your button is being dynamically generated in the `DOM` , then use **on-click** `event handler` like this :-

```
 $("#item").on('click',function(){
     toggleObjects('panelContent'); 
 });
```

Just remember don't pass the `id` alongwith `#` . As i can see you are comparing that `id` with the **currentObject** in your **toggleObject()** and i hope that would not be something beginning with `#`.

But If the **currentObject** is beginning with `#` then , whatever you wrote in the `HTML` will work and for jQuery , instead of doing  **toggleObjects('panelContent');**  inside the `click` and `on-click` **EVENT HANDLERS**  just add `#` too at the beginning of panelContent ( **toggleObjects('#panelContent');** )

Thanks !!